# nodejs + nginx getting 502 error when using https module instead of http

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https

I have make my nodejs app, hosted it on digital ocean server connect it to domain name, and all works fine, but when i'm trying to put ssl certificate (using https module instead of http), it doesn't works. Here is a code:

```
var sslopt = {

    key  : fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt'),
    ca   : [fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca2.crt')]

};

var server = https.createServer(sslopt,function(req,res){
    ...
});

server.listen(8001,function(err){
    ...
});
```

My nodejs app running fine but if i'm trying to access it, I just see the 502 Bad Gateway error, and no requests was sent to my nodejs app. When I have opened my nginx error log I see the errors

-date- -time- [error] 18116#18116: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: -ip-, server: -server-, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: -host-

But the most strange thing that if I'm trying to get access with https protocol and port 8001 (https://{domainname}.com:8001) I can see my app working fine, but connection is not secured.

I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

P.S.

my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen *:443;
listen *:80;


    server_name {myhostname};

    access_log /var/log/nginx/qt.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/qt.error.log;

    root /srv/qt;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    # Headers to pass to proxy server.
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    # Go to next upstream after if server down.
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    # Gateway timeout.
    proxy_read_timeout 20s;
    proxy_send_timeout 20s;
    # Buffer settings.
    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;




    location  / {



        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }

}
```

Comment: `proxy_pass` is set to `http://`, not `https://`. However, I would advise that instead of having Node handle HTTPS, you let NGINX do it (so _"client-to-NGINX"_ is HTTPS and _"NGINX-to-Node"_ is plain HTTP).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I attaching certificate to the nginx and then using http instead of https all working fine, but I can't connect to the websocket server now. In console I see the error.

WebSocket connection to 'wss://{hostname}:8001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

And no requests sent to my websocket server log

Comment: You should let NGINX proxy your websockets for you: `wss://{hostname}` (no port number required)

Comment: Now It responds me 
connection to 'wss://{hostname}/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
And in my console I see that it goes as simple http request...

Comment: Maybe I need to set up something on my nginx config?

Comment: At first glance, it looks okay. Can you check (in your browser's dev console) what the response contains? Also, you're using regular websockets and not `socket.io`, right?

Comment: It responds 1006 error Connections Closed. 
Right. Regular websockets.

Comment: The NGINX configuration to proxy websockets is documented here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ From what I can see, your config already contains the proper values (although it also contains a lot of other stuff which may be interfering, not sure). Just to make sure the issue isn't Node, try and see if this works: `ws://{hostname}:8001`

Comment: didn't help... Again first error displayed. But all works fine if i'm using http connection

Comment: This looks useful: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/257#issuecomment-41728931 Perhaps it's a TLS issue. Did you add the CA certificates to NGINX as well? How to do that is documented here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html (search for _"SSL certificate chains"_)

Comment: CA is added as well. But when i'm test my domain name on sslshopper service i see that Intermediate/chain is not working. Can it be the problem for websocket?

Comment: That might be a problem, although I'd assume that regular HTTPS requests would also cause issues in that situation. Perhaps it's easier (for now) to move the HTTPS-part back to Node :(

Comment: ok, thank you so much!

Comment: I have fixed ssl certificate, but its doesn't helps. 
I'm getting 
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when using wss

Comment: The comment I linked to earlier (https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/257#issuecomment-41728931) mentions a tool called `wscat` that you could try and use for debugging the WSS connection: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that this is an old post, hopefully this will still help someone out.  I just figured out what seems to be the same thing and it was proxy server related.

My NodeJS server worked fine without SSL but gave the 502 without ever reaching the server when I used https.

```
// =============================================================================
// START THE SERVER

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

https.createServer({
     key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/private.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.crt')
 }, app).listen(port);

//app.listen(port);

console.log('API Active on port ' + port);
```

My client and server are behind a pfSense firewall using a Squid3 proxy server.

pfSense controls the DNS for api.mydomain.com and routes the traffic to my dev server when I make a call to api.mydomain.com:8080/myroute.  I have a valid SSL/TLS cert for api.mydomain.com

- With the app.listen(port) line uncommented everything worked great.
- With the https.createServer(...) uncommented I got the 502 error and traffic never reached the server.

To fix:

1. In pfSense click Services -> Squid Proxy Server
2. Click on the ACLs
   configuration page
3. At the bottom of the page find the section
   called Squid Allowed Ports.
4. In the field For ACL SSL Ports, enter the port your
   application is using (in my case 8080).

For me, rainbows appeared and bluebirds did sing.